# uploading a specific style to paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I know that with modern paperclip I can do

```
model.source = URI.parse source_url
```

and that will download the file and handle everything for me.
However, what if I want to provide styles that have already been processed internally.
Something like

```
model.upload_source 'video/mp4', (URI.parse source_url_mp4)
model.upload_source 'video/webm', (URI.parse source_url_webm)
```

I'm not finding this documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered finding the mimetype in your application code after loading a source_url?

Comment: I would like for it to work transparently with other code that does

    source(:mp4)